# Generate input submit for each column from sql table

Tags: php, mysql, input

I have a MySQL Table with 34 columns and need a Submit Button for each one with the value identical to the column name in order to perform an SQL Query on submit. Example:

```
<input type="submit" name="column1" value="column1" />
<input type="submit" name="column2" value="column2" />
//etc.
```

Is there any method to generate the inputs automatically with the required names and values? Also to automatically generate a new submit input when I add another column to the table?

The farthest I've come is this:

```
$connect = mysql_connect("localhost","user","pass");
mysql_select_db("db1");
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tb1");
echo "<input type="submit" name="$db" value="$db" />";
```

This is, of course, absolute rubbish. But, as I was saying, this is as far as I've come. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here. This will generate lots of submit buttons but each one of them is going to have the same behaviour - sending the entire form.

Comment: I need all the submit buttons. And they're not going to have the same action because I set `if(isset($_POST['column1'])){ //do action1 }` `if(isset($_POST['column2'])){ //do action2 }`, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to loop through your results and echo your input button inside it.

Also, you can display a button for each column in your table, but for that you will need to know how many columns your table have. You achieve this at least in two ways:

1. You can use an SQL query:

   ```
   SELECT count(*)
   FROM information_schema.columns
   WHERE table_name = 'tbl_YOURTABLE'
   ```
2. In your loop, you can count the number of elements / index exists in the array using, for example, the [count function](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.count.php) of php.

Comment: That looks very complex. Just use 'show columns' instead

Comment: If the user needs a button for each column on each row that exists on the table (and note just a button for each column), the solution will necessarily involve a loop through the rows. So, considering this, i think that my solution is that complex. In this case, the solution using the count function inside the loop is a good approach to avoid the need of making 2 querys to the database (one to retrieve the data and another to retrieve the list of columns in the table).

Comment: You're right. Well he asked for one button for every column. Just not clear. Let's choose him :D

Comment: When I try: 
`$columns = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM information_schema.COLUMNS WHERE table_name = 'tb1'");` and `echo $columns;`, all I get is `Resource id #5`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the query 'show columns from table'  to get all cols. Just loop them and create a submit for each. But pls var_dump the result first since this query not only returns the col name but a few other info. Anyway as said in the comment: each input will submit the whole form. You then can check which one was clicked by checking the name of the input